# Dual Display on Macbook Pro 9,1 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, multiple-monitors, bumblebee, macbook-pro

I successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my macbook pro 9,1.
Everything is now working correctly. Except I am unable to plug in a second screen.

If I plug in another screen :

1. At system Boot: I get no display(black screen) after the initial console messages related to system start. Though in the black screen if I press `ctrl+alt+f2` -> `type my username` -> `type my password` -> `type sudo reboot` -> `type password`. Then I can still reboot successfully.
2. At runtime: I can see the second screen being detected by nvidia-setting page. But still the second screen has no display

I have tried the following:

1. Change the drivers to Nouveau drivers
2. Use the Nvidia 331.38 drivers
3. Install BumbleBee: This gave me a black screen on my main monitor and I had to reinstall the Nvidia drivers after removing bumblebee. I was using [this](http://www.unixreich.com/blog/2013/linux-nvidia-optimus-on-thinkpad-w520w530-with-external-monitor-finally-solved/) link for installing bumbleBee.But after rebooting my display goes away.

the output for `lspci | grep VGA is:`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
```

Please advice how I can have the second screen on my Macbook pro.
My current driver version : 331.67

Updates:
1. When I connected DisplayPort-to-HDMI converter to my HDMI TV screen the second display started working as it is. I then tested my old monitor(which only has D-sub connector) using the chain:

DisplayPort-to-HDMI adapter-> HDMI-DSub adapter->DSub input of my monitor.

After changing to the correct resolution, my monitor is now acting as a secondary display.
So I guess the problem is either :
1. With Display-port to D-Sub adapter I have(its china made)
2. OR there is a problem with all the Display-port to D-Sub adapters.
I will test my friends adapter and post here later.

Comment: Are you sure you got the model number right? It seems like 9,2 is the 2012 13 inch model which doesn't have nvidia graphics..

Comment: Hi @Anake ,yeah I made a mistake. Corrected it now. Its 9,1 got it by typing 'sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name'

Comment: Have you found any thing useful?

Comment: nope still stuck with one display :(

Comment: Have you tried turning off the Nvidia card (blacklist nouveau or whatever) and just using the Intel graphics? Intel graphics work great with dual or triple display on a Macbook.

Comment: I had to disable nvidia from osx to get it to work. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2137538